# How can I have more than 10 entries in the iftop text output?

Tags: debian, network-interface, iftop

I want to monitor the network traffic and save the results to a file under Debian Linux. I am using `iftop` to achieve this.

Following command does the job:

```
iftop -tnNBP -s 3600 -o destination > output.txt 2>&1
```

My problem is: if more than 10 connections are present during the monitoring time (1 hour), only the first 10 is saved to the `output.txt` file. The rest of the connections are not shown.

How can I configure the `iftop` to display all of the connection (regardless how much they are/were).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find it in [`iftop`'s configuration file documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/iftop/iftop.8#CONFIG_FILE) but I did find it in the [sou](https://code.blinkace.com/pdw/iftop/blob/master/options.c#L167)[rce](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/iftop/-/blob/debian/1.0_pre4-4/options.c#L160):

> ```
> 167    options.num_lines = 10;
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> 587     options_config_get_int("num-lines", &options.num_lines);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> 297            case 'L':
> 298                 config_set_string("num-lines", optarg);
> 299                 break;
> ```

- **UPDATE:** but actually, as @GAD3R kindly told me, this information is also available in the command's built-in help:

  ```
  # iftop --usage
  [...]
     The following options are only available in combination with -t
     -s num              print one single text output afer num seconds, then quit
     -L num              number of lines to print
  ```

The option is thus `-L`. Values 0 or -1 won't help (no result displayed):

```
iftop -L 2000000000 -tnNBP -s 3600 -o destination > output.txt 2>&1
```

should do what you're looking for (up to 2000000000 lines). Or alternatively, you can use this configuration option in the `~/.iftoprc` file:

```
num-lines:2000000000
```

which will be used only if the command is run with `-t` or the other configuration option `no-curses:true` is also present.

and run as usual:

```
iftop -tnNBP -s 3600 -o destination > output.txt 2>&1
```